# ¿ Como puedo llenar esta matriz con valores del abecedario?

Tags: c

Tenía una consulta debido a que tengo una matriz de 5x5 y le estoy ingresando la siguiente frase:`algoritmsypcn` , una vez ingresada la frase a la matriz debo llenar los espacios restantes (que se encuentran vacío) con letras del abecedario, **siempre y cuando la letra no se encuentre en la frase ingresada**.

Introduzco un ejemplo:

[image]

Hasta el momento tengo esto en el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char mat[5][5]; //tamaño de la matriz
    char letras[]="algoritmsypcn";
    int i, j, x = 0;
    char abecedario[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // Ingresar estos valores en los espacios sobrantes de la matriz, siempre y cuando no se repitan.
  
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++) 
        {
           mat[i][j]=letras[x];
           ++x;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("[%c]",mat[i][j]);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Es obligatorio usar una matriz? Lo veo innecesario, ya que todo se lo puede hacer en un mismo *array* unidimensional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es verificar si la matriz contiene o no el caracter antes de añadirlo.

En cualquier caso, nota que no te hace falta el array `abecedario`. Puedes pasar de una letra a la siguiente simplemente sumando `1` al caracter:

```
char c = 'a';
printf("%c", c); // imprime a
c = c + 1;
printf("%c", c); // imprime b
```

Asi que, como ves, puedes reemplezar facilmente un array por una única variable de tipo `char`

Por otro lado, nota que un array de tamaño fijo (`char mat[5][5]`), es una estructura que se almacena en la pila del programa... esto hace que, necesariamente, el array se almacene de forma linealizada en dicha pila. Esto quiere decir que, en memoria, primero nos encontraremos la primera fila, después la segunda seguida de la tercera y así:

```
// La estructura que tu ves en código
mat ->  0  1  2  3  4
        5  6  7  8  9
       10 11 12 13 14
       15 16 17 18 19
       20 21 22 23 24

// La estructura en memoria
mat ->  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 ...
```

Esta particularidad permite que puedas manejar la matriz como si fuese un vector, lo que simplifica enormemente los cálculos:

```
char mat[5][5];

char *ptr = (char*)mat; // Puntero para tratar la matriz como si fuese un vector

// Copiamos la frase en la matriz
for( int i=0; letras[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++ptr )
{
  *ptr = letras[i];
}

// Rellenamos el resto de la matriz
char siguiente_letra = 'a';
for( ; ptr <= &mat[4][4]; ++ptr )
{
  // Primero buscamos una letra que no este ya en la matriz
  int existe;
  do
  {
    existe = 0;
    for( char * it = (char*)mat; it != ptr && !existe; ++it )
    {
      existe = (*it == siguiente_letra);
    }

    // Si la letra ya esta en la matriz, pasamos a la siguiente
    if( existe ) ++siguiente_letra;
  } while( existe == 1);

  // Copiamos la letra elegida en la matriz
  *ptr = siguiente_letra;
}
```